# 2 questions about Ramana Maharshi

Tags: neo-vedanta

1. what is the 'martial garland'?  is that a hymn developed by Ramana Maharshi?  or a custom for collecting alms or something else?
2. Was Ramana Maharshi unhappy during his later ashram life due to his increasing popularity, his inability to remain reclusive, privacy, etc. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ans to Q1:
It is a beautiful hymn sung by Sri Ramana Maharshi.
Can be found at:
http://www.arunachala-live.com/108_verses.php
Briefly the theme goes like this:
Gracious Ganapati! with Thy (loving) hand bless me, that I may make this a marital garland of letters worthy of Sri Arunachala, the bridegroom!

REFRAIN

Arunachala Shiva! Arunachala Shiva!
Arunachala Shiva! Arunachala!
Arunachala Shiva! Arunachala Shiva!
Arunachala Shiva! Arunachala!

1. (a)* Thou dost root out the ego of those who meditate on Thee in the heart, O Arunachala!
   (b) Thou dost root out the ego of those who dwell on their (spiritual) identity with Thee, O Arunachala!

Ans to Q2:
Many people say that he shunned publicity.
Just a write-up on the link
Link:https://mydattatreya.com/ramana-maharshi/

I have an opinion about him, but who am I.